# Multi-Level Permalinks for Custom Post Types using ACF field values

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a client site with several custom post types - region, county, city, community. I want to set up dynamically generated permalink structures for them as follows:

/[region]

/[region]/[county]

/[region]/[county]/[city]

/[region]/[county]/[city]/[community]

I have added a filter for post_type_link and am passing in a function that is updating the permalinks:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', array(&$this, 'rewriteCPTpermalinks'), 10, 2);

/**
   * Rewrite Custom Post Type Permalinks
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function rewriteCPTpermalinks( $url, $post ){
    global $wp_rewrite;

    if ($post->post_type === 'counties') {
        $regionObject = get_field('region', $post->ID );
        // $url = get_the_permalink($regionObject->ID).$post->post_name;
        $url = str_replace( '%region%', get_the_permalink($regionObject->ID), $url );
    }
    if ($post->post_type == 'cities') {
      $countyObject = get_field('county', $post->ID);
      $regionObject = get_field('region', $countyObject->ID );
      $url = get_the_permalink($regionObject->ID).$countyObject->post_name.'/'.$post->post_name;
    }
    if ($post->post_type == 'communities') {
      $cityObject = get_field('city_post', $post->ID);
      $countyObject = get_field('county', $cityObject->ID);
      $regionObject = get_field( 'region', $countyObject->ID );
      $url = $regionObject->post_name.$countyObject->post_name.'/'.$cityObject->post_name.'/'.$post->post_name;
    }
    
    return $url;

  }
```

This is updating the permalinks but I am getting a 404 page for all posts. I have saved permalinks in Settings > Permalinks and tried `flush_rewrite_rules()` but cannot seem to get these working.

The key for this is to have things work automatically without having to choose from a custom taxonomy for every post.

I'm not sure if I am using the right approach here but would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hello
What method did you use to add custom post type?
You'll need to add a post and add [region] / [county] / [city] / [community] as taxonomy, the rest will be done automatically.

Comment: Hi - I registered the custom post types in the code base. I have custom taxonomies set up and tried using them with by setting the rewrite property with the post type to ```%region%``` and then changing my function to replace that tag with the custom ACF field value for the region object post field. I end up with the same result - the string for the URL is updated, but the actual permalink is not rewritten so I get a 404.

Comment: The key thing is that using a custom taxonomy seems to require assigning the taxonomy to every post. This is too much work as we have 70+ community posts and would have to assign a region, county and city to each one. I am looking for an automated solution that will rewrite permalinks for existing posts, as well as new posts.